# How can i define variables for All hosts in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I know that there are several ways of defining variables like:

- Inside Inventory
- Inside Playbook
- Inside Include Files
- Inside `host_vars` and `groups_var` Variables Per host and group.

But how to create place, file, whatever to store variables for **ALL** hosts similar to `host_vars`.

Is it Even Possible? I know that it is possible to include a file with variables, but i want to know, is it possible to import them automatically like `host_vars`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`all` is an implicit group with the inventory system.

You could create `group_vars/all.yml` and put the variables in there.

Several other ways to do it also, I'd think.

The [variables doco](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#defining-variables-in-included-files-and-roles) says you can use variables from (automatically) included files just like [roles](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#role-default-variables) does.

Comment: So all is the group itself. Thanks - i will also check for roles. It looks like he wanted to say group_var/all.yml (this is the way how it is described in documentation he provided).